# How do I put a WHERE LIKE in to this SQL SELECT?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-like

I have this SQL and PHP:

```
$articles = returndata("
     SELECT 
         (SELECT COUNT(*) from blog_posts) as totalcount,
         (SELECT COUNT(*) from comments where assetid = d.assetid) as replies,
         c.name as categoryname,
         d.category as categoryid,
         d.assetid, 
         d.title,
         d.postdate,
         d.articlecontent
     FROM blog_categories c 
         INNER JOIN 
         blog_posts d 
     GROUP BY d.assetid 
     ORDER BY postdate DESC 
         LIMIT " . (($page - 1) * $size) . ", " . $size
, $database);
```

I also have a variable, $query, which contains a multi-word query (like "hello world") and I want to search my database with this. I have tried the correct things (I think) but it keeps returning 0.

Comment: The `ON` clause is missing, too.

Comment: What field in what table are you trying to search?  There is no SQL command to "search [a] database}.

Comment: Sorry! I see now that I forgot that. I am trying to find the results in "d.title" which is the title field in the blog_posts table. Idealy, I would like to search in articlecontent, too, and return the rank (i.e. the number of times the string is found) as an extra field... I am getting out of my depth with this project >.<

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this ::

```
SELECT 
(SELECT COUNT(*) from blog_posts) as totalcount, 
(SELECT COUNT(*) from comments where assetid = d.assetid) as replies, 
c.name as categoryname, 
d.category as categoryid, 
d.assetid, 
d.title, 
d.postdate, 
d.articlecontent 
FROM blog_categories c 
INNER JOIN blog_posts d on // join condition
// THE WHERE CLAUSE SHOULD BE HERE LIKE column like '%sample word%'


GROUP BY d.assetid ORDER BY postdate DESC LIMIT
```

Comment: I am still getting an error? I assume I am doing something stupid here. I did not know how to use the "on" statement (alas) and my code is now: `$articles = returndata("SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*) from blog_posts) as totalcount, (SELECT COUNT(*) from comments where assetid = d.assetid) as replies, c.name as categoryname, d.category as categoryid, d.assetid, d.title, d.postdate, d.articlecontent FROM blog_categories c INNER JOIN blog_posts d WHERE d.title LIKE '%" . $query . "%' GROUP BY d.assetid ORDER BY postdate DESC LIMIT " . (($page - 1) * $size) . ", " . $size, $database);`

Comment: Sorry about this post... I am usually better on Stackoverflow. I kinda screwed up a bit! The error is now resolved. It turned out it was my database handling code did not know what to do when it returned zero rows. This has now been resolved.